# Docker Chains will be reset by iptables

Tags: docker, reset, iptables, flush

actually I have some issues with my Docker service.
After a few min, the following rules just will be deleted by the iptables.

Iptables after:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  x.x.x.x        anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain trafficfilter (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Iptables before:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  113.100.50.1         anywhere
DROP       all  --  200.77.191.71        anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain trafficfilter (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

As you can see, there are a few Chains like DOCKER-USER,ISOLATION and more..
It works for like 1-10 Min but after that, the rules just disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found it.
I just did
service docker restart
and after that, I just save the correct iptables with persistent into the rule.v4 file.

It works perfect now!